# Using JFiddle to create web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand how to convert the following JFiddle example into a single html web page: **http://jsfiddle.net/zqa511e9/**

What am doing wrong? Both the style and javascript code are not being reflected in the form. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Expandable Text Area</title>

<style>
textarea {
width: 200px;
height:15px;
line-height:15px;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 300px;
transition: width 0.25s;
resize:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<script> 
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
if(e.which == 13) {e.preventDefault();}
}).on('input', function(){
$(this).height(1);
var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - 
parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
$(this).height(totalHeight);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<textarea placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }'>
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need external resources: jquery and jquery.autosize.input.js

Comment: How exactly do I add that to the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Updated Code.

You Need to do two things.
1. SImport Jquery Library.
2. Write on load in javascript block.

Try This

```
<title>Expandable Text Area</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
textarea {
width: 200px;
height:15px;
line-height:15px;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 300px;
transition: width 0.25s;
resize:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {e.preventDefault();}
    }).on('input', function(){
    $(this).height(1);
    var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - 
    parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
    $(this).height(totalHeight);
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<textarea placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }'>
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I write onload in the javascript block?

Comment: I have already done it in example. Try running it in your local.

Comment: ... I tried again and its working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For one you are using jQuery, but there is no link to jQuery in your html. Jfiddle has it automatically applied I think.

Grab a jQuery CDN and place it in the head tag like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Pratiyush's code works.
I had to add the jquery link as you mentioned and fix the javascript block.
Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

You need external resources: jquery and jquery.autosize.input.js

In your html put this code between the head tag

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autosize.js/3.0.20/autosize.min.js"></script>
</head>
```